# How to attach screenshot in Jenkins email notification

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testing, devops

I am executing a few testcases on the VM wherein each time when the tests run a screenshot folder is created and all the screenshots are added in the screenshot folder on the VM

My question is:-

1. Is it possible to attach the screenshot folder in the Jenkins email?If yes then how
2. Is it possible to click on Testcase link in the email and get the screenshots of the respective testcase? If yes then how

Answer (score 0):

1. Add editable email plugin to your jenkins
2. Then pass the report location in your configure section.
3. **/*.png **or** **/*.jpg

**Plugin name :**
[image]

**Attachment Path :**
[image]

Comment: I am running my tests on a VM so when I used the above email configuration I see a report with the broken image icon.

Comment: Then manually download the report from VM. I hope generated html is broken